# A successful login is not giving me the required cookies to access other pages (using Jsoup)

Tags: java, cookies, authentication, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to login to a website via the programming interface (using Java with Jsoup) and save the response cookie so I can pass it onto following requests. But there is no cookie in the response header after I login :(

I did manage to login successfully however there is no cookies in the response header. For debugging purpose I logged in from the chrome browser and checked the response header using chrome network tab and after I click the "login" button it successfully logs me in to the index page but without any cookies in the response header. I know I need the cookies to access other pages that require login because their request header has a cookie called "SESSION..." and I never received that cookie in the response header.

Would someone please help me identify the problem here? I've posted the code to login below. This is the website www.lib.uts.edu.au

```
Connection.Reponse res = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .data("username", id
                    , "password", password
                    , "lt", ltVal
                    , "_eventId", "submit"
                    , "sso_submit", "Sign In"
                    , "rememberMe", "true")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();
```

Comment: can you share the URL address? It is hard to guess what is going on without that info.

Comment: @luksch Hi. The url address of the post request is https://www.lib.uts.edu.au/auth/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lib.uts.edu.au%2Fcas%3Fcas_load_iframe%3D1%26destination%3Ddashboard&iframe=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong call, often the cookie is set in the previous call to the login one (the one that load the login form).

If you try this snippet of code:

```
    //This url loads the login form
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.lib.uts.edu.au/auth/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lib.uts.edu.au%2Fcas%3Fcas_load_iframe%3D1%26destination%3Ddashboard&iframe=true")
            .timeout(300000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

    System.out.println("JSESSIONID=" + response.cookies().get("JSESSIONID"));
```

You'll see something like:

```
JSESSIONID=E16B98E972FFF05E9091453C01779E67
```

I hope you'll have there the session cookie you're looking for, just remember to use that cookie in login and succesive calls.

--- EDIT ---

There is another uri that sets a SSESS012... cookie and then redirects to the url I mentioned in my original answer, please try this:

```
    //Try this other url
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.lib.uts.edu.au/cas?destination=dashboard&cas_load_iframe=1")
            .timeout(300000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

    System.out.println("JSESSIONID=" + response.cookies().get("JSESSIONID"));
    System.out.println("SSESS012...=" + response.cookies().get("SSESS012ea49d58f199a67a953e1500684490"));
```

Now you'll see something similar to:

```
JSESSIONID=5466DCD5601415175514AA88FEC967A0
SSESS012...=DfL4tW0xOdfu_9Op52b-z3El3CNG2xxOYZdruuVfWH0
```

I hope this is what you needed :)

Comment: Hi fonkap, I truly appreciate your time to respond to my question. 
Unfortunately "JSESSIONID" is not the cookie required to access other pages, it is only required for the login process and I did manage to successfully login with that cookie. 
My problem is that I am not receiving the necessary cookies I need to access the pages after I login successfully. So even if I've logged in, if I try to access other pages (for example, dashboard, which requires authentication) the server will redirect me to the login page because I don't have the required cookies.

Comment: I tried to upload a screenshot of the cookies required for the pages but stackoverflow does not allow me to upload images because i dont have enough reputation. but basically in the network tab under the Cookies section of the dashboard page, in the "Request cookies" tab there are two cookies called "SESS012ea49....49" & "SSESS012ea49d5....84490". I believe these are the cookies required but I am not receiving them when I login successfully.

Comment: Oh and yes I have already loaded the form first and then logged in like you suggested above. My apologies...should have mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Ah ok! Sorry I misunderstood! Answering again: There is another call that sets the cookie you are looking for, https://www.lib.uts.edu.au/cas?destination=dashboard&cas_load_iframe=1 that call will set a cookie named SSESS012.... and then will redirect to ...auth/login?... . Now I am very busy, but in a few hours I will update my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: oh my god fonkap you are my hero...IT FINALLY WORKED!! I did as you mentioned in your answer, retrieved the cookies from the url you gave me, and then passed  the cookies to the redirected login url which gave me a successful login AND the very two cookies I needed. It is so confusing how this site has different login urls....Thank you so much!!

Comment: Right now I just don't have enough rep to accept this as an answer, but I've voted it up so as soon as I get enough rep it will be publicly displayed. Once again I truly appreciate your kind help. you solved what took me about two weeks in a single comment :)

Comment: I'm very glad it helped. I agree that it's confusing this double url/cookie mechanism. By the way, I can share a little trick, if you use the browser and do the login with developer tools (F12) open, in the network tab you can see the different calls that are made (including request and respone headers!) that info is super-useful for making robots/scrappers with jsoup (or any other tool)

Comment: Another nice trick (maybe you already know, but anyway) Is that you can use  developer tools to find a tag in a html page, then right click and 'Copy CSS Path'. This will give you the selector you can use in JSoup! It is very time saving!

Comment: I actually did utilise the developer tools but I guess I did not inspect the request/response header closely enough to find out the double cookies mechanism, once again I've learned the importance of attention to details the hard way :) And plus this is my first encounter with such login system and your guidance really set me in the right track. Thanks for the CSS trick, I wasn't aware of that technique and it'll come in handy in further development :) Thank you for your help & tips! (btw ur answer is accepted now!)