# Jsoup empty login response cookies

Tags: java, cookies, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to login to a website using Jsoup. However, after a successful login my Connection.Response instance is not returning any cookies. 
Here is the code:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://id.wsj.com/access/pages/wsj/us/signin.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wsj.com&mg=id-wsj")
        .data("landing_page", "http://online.wsj.com", "login_realm", "default", "login_template", "default", 
        "username", "username", "password", "password", "savelogin", "checked", "submitButton", "Sign In").method(Method.POST).execute();
        doc2 = res.parse();
        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
        doc = Jsoup.connect("url").cookies(loginCookies).get();
```

Where the

```
res.cookies()
```

method is returning an empty Map.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass in **ALL** input fields to your request? You need to include EVERY SINGLE input fields **INCLUDING** hidden fields! I see you only passed in ID and password, that seems to be the problem.

---

If you are using the **Chrome** browser, right-click on the page and select "Inspect Elements". This will invoke the `Developer Tools` to appear. Go to console and type in **$("input")**. This will give you all the input fields present in that page. Something like the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify please? What other hidden input fields? How would I find them?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question to reflect your suggestion, but I am still returning an empty map. Is it possible that since the submitButton input I am referencing does not have a name but rather I am referencing its ID that is creating a problem?

Comment: Hey, instead of your url, would you try the following one? `https://id.wsj.com/auth/submitlogin.json`

Comment: I appreciate your help again, but that url simply produced a null document, I do not think it is the url I need

Comment: Interesting...because sometimes it is the url that causes the problem (using the wrong url). I've had this kind of issue and solved it with a different url, maybe it could be of help to you, the link is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163801/a-successful-login-is-not-giving-me-the-required-cookies-to-access-other-pages

Comment: Perhaps I can try using the `.cookie` method instead, although I'm having trouble selecting the right cookie name, how would I determine the name of the appropriate cookie?